# Converting hh:mm:ss to rounded minutes in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

In Database, I have a field which give me data in `hh:mm:ss` format.

I want to convert that into total minutes using MySQL not PHP. For example, if value in Database is `00:20:12`, the o/p will be 21 after round up.

Comment: What is the type of the field?  A string?  `time`?  Something else?

Comment: field type is varchar

Comment: Round 00:20:12 to 00:21? Isn't that ceiling?

Comment: ***@user3048016***: `SELECT CEIL( TIME_TO_SEC( TIME( '00:20:12' ) ) / 60 ) AS mins`

Comment: It is correct. Thank you Ravinder.

Comment: Thank you all for your efforts.

Comment: @RavinderReddy why not an answer?

Comment: Using a varchar for date/time value is bound to cause trouble. The best answer starts with converting the column to a datetime, time or timestamp column. Anything else is poor design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have timestamps, or if you can convert the value to timestamps, then you can do a calculation like this:

```
SELECT
  TheTimeStamp,
  CASE WHEN MOD(TheTimeStamp, 60) = 0 THEN
    TheTimeStamp
  ELSE
    TheTimeStamp + 60 - MOD(TheTimeStamp, 60)
  END AS TheCeiledTimeStamp
FROM
  YourTable
```

Comment: but in this case, when value is 00:00:00 it also returns 00:00:00. :(

Comment: it should return simply 0(zero)

Comment: @user3048016: It is not that *simple*

Comment: I'm rather surprised that this is the accepted answer, because from what I can tell, the code would generate an error on the data provided by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this in MySQL:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN RIGHT('00:20:01',2) != '00' THEN CAST(CAST(RIGHT(LEFT('00:20:12',5),2) AS UNSIGNED) +1 AS VARCHAR(20)) ELSE RIGHT(LEFT('00:20:12',5),2) END
```